# Error yarn and esbuild 'The linux-x64 architecture is incompatible with this module, link skipped.'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-5, yarnpkg, esbuild

I try to install bootstrap 5 and popper via esbuild.

I inatalled esbuild `npm install esbuild`, run `npm install bootstrap` and `npm i popper`.

Than I added gems :

```
gem "jsbundling-rails", "~> 1.0"
gem "cssbundling-rails", "~> 1.1"
```

and run

```
rails css:install:bootstrap
rails javascript:install:esbuild
```

After each command esbuild or yearn I get next errors:

```
➤ YN0000: ┌ Link step
➤ YN0076: │ @esbuild/android-arm@npm:0.15.15 The linux-x64 architecture is incompatible with this module, link skipped.
➤ YN0076: │ @esbuild/linux-loong64@npm:0.15.15 The linux-x64 architecture is incompatible with this module, link skipped.
➤ YN0076: │ esbuild-android-64@npm:0.15.15 The linux-x64 architecture is incompatible with this module, link skipped.
➤ YN0076: │ esbuild-android-arm64@npm:0.15.15 The linux-x64 architecture is incompatible with this module, link skipped.
➤ YN0076: │ esbuild-darwin-64@npm:0.15.15 The linux-x64 architecture is incompatible with this module, link skipped.
➤ YN0076: │ esbuild-darwin-arm64@npm:0.15.15 The linux-x64 architecture is incompatible with this module, link skipped.
➤ YN0076: │ esbuild-freebsd-64@npm:0.15.15 The linux-x64 architecture is incompatible with this module, link skipped.
➤ YN0076: │ esbuild-freebsd-arm64@npm:0.15.15 The linux-x64 architecture is incompatible with this module, link skipped.
➤ YN0076: │ esbuild-linux-32@npm:0.15.15 The linux-x64 architecture is incompatible with this module, link skipped.
➤ YN0076: │ esbuild-linux-arm64@npm:0.15.15 The linux-x64 architecture is incompatible with this module, link skipped.
➤ YN0076: │ esbuild-linux-arm@npm:0.15.15 The linux-x64 architecture is incompatible with this module, link skipped.
➤ YN0076: │ esbuild-linux-mips64le@npm:0.15.15 The linux-x64 architecture is incompatible with this module, link skipped.
➤ YN0076: │ esbuild-linux-ppc64le@npm:0.15.15 The linux-x64 architecture is incompatible with this module, link skipped.
➤ YN0076: │ esbuild-linux-riscv64@npm:0.15.15 The linux-x64 architecture is incompatible with this module, link skipped.
➤ YN0076: │ esbuild-linux-s390x@npm:0.15.15 The linux-x64 architecture is incompatible with this module, link skipped.
➤ YN0076: │ esbuild-netbsd-64@npm:0.15.15 The linux-x64 architecture is incompatible with this module, link skipped.
➤ YN0076: │ esbuild-openbsd-64@npm:0.15.15 The linux-x64 architecture is incompatible with this module, link skipped.
➤ YN0076: │ esbuild-sunos-64@npm:0.15.15 The linux-x64 architecture is incompatible with this module, link skipped.
➤ YN0076: │ esbuild-windows-32@npm:0.15.15 The linux-x64 architecture is incompatible with this module, link skipped.
➤ YN0076: │ esbuild-windows-64@npm:0.15.15 The linux-x64 architecture is incompatible with this module, link skipped.
➤ YN0076: │ esbuild-windows-arm64@npm:0.15.15 The linux-x64 architecture is incompatible with this module, link skipped.
➤ YN0076: │ fsevents@patch:fsevents@npm%3A2.3.2#~builtin<compat/fsevents>::version=2.3.2&hash=18f3a7 The linux-x64 architmpatible with this module, link skipped.
➤ YN0076: │ fsevents@patch:fsevents@npm%3A1.2.13#~builtin<compat/fsevents>::version=1.2.13&hash=18f3a7 The linux-x64 archcompatible with this module, link skipped.
➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 1s 89ms
➤ YN0000: Done with warnings in 2s 3ms
```

I use wsl Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS and Rails 7.
My package.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@hotwired/stimulus": "^3.1.1",
    "@hotwired/turbo-rails": "^7.2.4",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.10.2",
    "esbuild": "^0.15.15",
    "popper": "^1.0.1",
    "sass": "^1.56.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build:css": "sass ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.bootstrap.scss:./app/assets/builds/application.css --no-source-map --load-path=node_modules",
    "build": "esbuild app/javascript/*.* --bundle --sourcemap --outdir=app/assets/builds --public-path=assets"
  }
}
```

How to fix this errors?
I will be glad for help!